# How to make a button respond to touch event even if the touch's location is not contained in the button's rect ？

Tags: ios, objective-c

TODO: 
  I want make a button  respond to all the touch event located in the superview, which contains a textfield  and a button.

HOW TO:
  I override the superView 's method hitTest:withEvent:, the superView which is a custom view .

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    BOOL isContained = [self pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    if (self.hidden || self.alpha <= 0.1 || self.userInteractionEnabled == NO || !isContained)return nil;
    return self.button;
}
```

beside that,I also do these:

I set the button 's target-action only forEvent: UITouchUpInside，the setup is
not working better。 the button can receive the touch event outside it,and always can be highlighten ,but sometime can calls the action when the touch point locate near outside the button,sometimes can't.

when I set the target-action method for Event:UITouchUpInside | |UITouchupOutside ，that works.

Question: Can someone explain this ? 
I have complete  Xcode project at the site:https://github.com/hansonboy/TestHit

maybe you can download ,and run it, and find the reason. thanks.

comments:I use Interface Builder to do these. Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton tracks some of the touch events(`tracking`==YES) but doesn't treat them as ones, that happen inside the control’s bounds(`touchInside`==NO). Just check the UIButton `tracking`, `touchInside` values in the `endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent` method.

Means, hit-testing mechanism works as expected: UIButton handles the event but doesn't trigger an action for the `TouchUpInside` control's event. And it is up to UIButton object to decide whether or not to generate this event. I found out that when a touch is pretty close to the superviews bounds, the UIButton's `pointInside:withEvent:` gets called. In your case it returns NO and the action is not triggered in the end.

As a solution I'd define a category or subclass UIButton in the next way:

```
@interface Button : UIButton
@end

@implementation Button

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.enabled || self.hidden || !self.userInteractionEnabled || self.alpha == 0) return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    CGPoint pnt = [self convertPoint:point toView:self.superview];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.superview.bounds, pnt);
}

@end
```